# The index of the first bit

Tags: haskell, bit-manipulation

I can see in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:bit how to convert from an Int, n, to a Bit that has the nth bit set, using

```
bit :: Int -> a
```

However, how can I do the inverse of this? (Assuming the input Bit just has 1 bit set in it?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [base-4.8.0.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#t:FiniteBits) there are

```
countLeadingZeros :: FiniteBits b => b -> Int
countTrailingZeros :: FiniteBits b => b -> Int
```

Those index the most-significant and least-significant set bits starting from the most-significant and least-significant ends respectively. Subtract from `finiteBitSize :: FiniteBits b => b -> Int` to count from the other end.

Answer (score 3):

`popCount $ x-1` does that, effectively by counting the number of trailing zeroes. Subtracting 1 turns the trailing zeroes into ones and resets the only one that should be there.

---

This is easy to adapt to a more general case without the assumption that only one bit of the input is set: `popCount $ complement x .&. (x-1)`

The main idea is the same, and the ANDing with the complement of `x` gets rid of the ones that aren't newly created by the subtraction (which are the only ones that should be counted).

Comment: Doesn't this return the lowest set bit. Like `0011001` will return `1`. `13` maps to `2`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem “(Assuming the input Bit just has 1 bit set in it?)”